# Numerical value of physical constants Mathematica 10

Tags: units, physical-constants

Is there a way to use the physical constants in calculations and have *Mathematica* 10 figure out the final unit and numerical magnitude?
When I try

```
pcM = N[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"]]
```

I simply get `1. h` without the numerical value of Planck constant. Subsequently, using this in all further steps, keeps the answer in h and does not work out units.

However, if I define the Planck constant by hand and use it in a calculation, everything works as expected. I am curious as to why the internally defined constants do not show up with numerical values.

Thanks,

Comment: what would you like the result to be, i.e. which units should it be with respect to?

Comment: I learned just a few days ago that one can (often) use `UnitConvert` for this sort of thing. `In[199]:= UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"]]

Out[199]= Quantity[6.626070*10^-34, (
 "Kilograms" ("Meters")^2)/("Seconds")]`

Comment: or `In[647]:= UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"], "eV*s"]
Out[647]= Quantity[4.135668*10^-15, "Electronvolts" "Seconds"]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In physics, the Planck constant may be used as a natural unit.

If you want to switch to another unit system, use `UnitConvert[]`.

For example, you can switch to standard SI units this way:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "PlanckConstant"], "SIBase"]
```

which will give you:

```
Quantity[6.626070*10^-34, ("Kilograms" ("Meters")^2)/("Seconds")]
```

This can be done at the end of calculation.

If you like to get rid of Quantity head, just do:

```
QuantityMagnitude[%]
```

which outputs:

```
6.626070*10^-34
```

Comment: you can also use `QuantityMagnitude` to get the value out.

Comment: @chuy, indeed, thank you!

Comment: Or just `UnitConvert` without the second argument, which assumes SI units.

Comment: @MarkAdler: definitely right! Though, of course, using the second argument is a bit more general. For example, in engeneering applications one unit measure can be used and in spectroscopy - something totally different.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Physical Constants Package by using

```
<< PhysicalConstants`
```

When you enter now

```
PlanckConstant
```

you directly get the Planck Constant. 
With

```
PlanckConstant/(Joule Second)
```

you get the Planck Constant without units.

Comment: True, but note that PhysicalConstants package is obsolete and has been biult into Mathematica since version 9.